# What to use instead of org.springframework.data.util.CacheValue in spring-data-commons 2

Tags: spring, spring-data

CacheValue doesn't exist anymore in spring-data-commons v2, I tried looking why it was removed and what to use instead but couldn't find something..

Comment: `java.util.Optional`, since Spring Data 2.0 requires Java 8 as a minimum. This is not documented anywhere, but can be quickly gleaned from the [JavaDocs of the original class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/1.13.9.RELEASE/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/util/CacheValue.java).

Comment: @manish thanks, I think you are right since the implementation is pretty similar to Optional. you may wanna make your comment as answer so we can close this one